# Should a student carry a sleeping bag with himself when going abroad?

Tags: usa, sleeping, boston

I am student who would be traveling to USA for higher studies. I have a sleeping bag that I have been using for camping. Would it be good if I carry it along with me? AFAIK students there buy mattresses but if I have a sleeping bag I would be saving money on buying a mattress.

Please correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 2):

Having done what you are embarking on 10 years ago, I may have some words of wisdom (IMHO obviously `;)`):

- Do you have accommodation (long term) figured out? If you have, did you get an inventory of items in the house (some owners do provide such inventories). If you haven't, there is a good chance that when you do rent a house/apartment, the owner will have spare bedding available. You will have to ask him/her. I have lived in a few university towns and I am yet to meet an international student who has had to purchase a mattress. Of course, I am sure the latter is true as well (people having to purchase mattresses)
- **Carrying a sleeping bag**: This is useful only if there are no major stores such as Walmart of sporting goods around your university/housing. However, if you think carrying a sleeping bag will ensure that you don't worry about the sleeping situation once you get there, by all means do! There is nothing worse than leaving a piece of baggage 15000 miles away only to realize that you could have used it. Having said that, be judicious in packing as I am certain there are baggage mass/weight limits imposed! `;)`

Good luck and have a great time in the United States!